# CSS (or not) animated image it becomes transparent onmouseover and then becomes untransparent again

Tags: css, image, transparency

heyo fellows gotta question, i have to make a picture that gets a bit transparent (like opacity 0,4), then it size increases like 2x and becomes untransparent again (opacity 1)
and the text all that time doesnt change its position.

```
img  {
         opacity: 1;
         width: 250;
         }
         img:hover {
    opacity: 0.4;
    filter: alpha(opacity=40);
        width: 500px; 
        transition-property: width;  
  transition-duration: 4s;

                         }
```

i've made a css code only for size increasing and transparency, however no idea how to make it opacity 1 again after my 4sec animation and no idea how to make the text stay in the very same position after image size increases.

Comment: Hi, Can you make a fiddle? So that we can see the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi I did not understand your problem properly. But here I think you wanted something like this.

**HTML**

```
<img src="http://t3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTCrT41Zwh43blojDO5tgu1qnsCXbz1Eu6dBiHipmGKjw-oAr7s8Q" alt>
```

**CSS**

```
@keyframes lI{
    0%{opacity:1; transform: scale(1);}
    50%{opacity:0.4; transform: scale(1.3);}
    100%{opacity:1; transform: scale(1.3);}
}

@-webkit-keyframes lI{
    0%{opacity:1; -webkit-transform: scale(1);}
    50%{opacity:0.4; -webkit-transform: scale(1.3);}
    100%{opacity:1; -webkit-transform: scale(1.3);}
}

img{
    display: block;
    opacity: 1;
    transform: scale(1);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
}

img:hover{
    animation: lI 4s linear 1 forwards;
    -webkit-animation: lI 4s linear 1 forwards;
}
```

Please check this [Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/e7zfwncn/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/e7zfwncn/1/). It uses CSS3 animation.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one solution but without more information it's hard to give you the best possible answer. You can only apply effect on hover with css, which means that picture will go back to normal once the picture is not hovered anymore. If you want a solution that will go back to normal automatically after 4s then you should use javascript.

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
}
figure {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 120px; /* It has to be bigger than twice the size of your picture if you don't want the text to move */
}
img {
  width: 50px;
  height: auto;
  -webkit-transition: width, 0, 4s;
  transition: width, 0, 4s;
}
img:hover {
  width: 100px; /* twice the original size */
  opacity: .4;
}
.text {
  display: inline-block; /* so that your text is aligned with picture */
  vertical-align: top; /* so that your text doesn't move */
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <figure>
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100">
  </figure>
  <div class="text">
    Some text...
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you add your transition in CSS to the img and not hover, then you will get the transition to work on both the mouse in and mouse out.

http://jsfiddle.net/shannabarnard/v7c9y6qj/

HTML

```
<img src="http://www.w3schools.com/tags/smiley.gif" alt="Smiley face" height="42" width="42">
```

CSS

```
img  {
    opacity: 1;
    transition: all 4s ease; 
}
img:hover {
    opacity: 0.4;
    filter: alpha(opacity=40);
    width: 84px; /* twice the original size */
    height: 84px; /* twice the original size */
}
```